# Crosstab Queries: using fixed values to create additional columns

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Has anyone read the MSDN page on using the TRANSFORM statement to create crosstab queries?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208956(v=office.12).aspx

It includes the following assertion, unsupported by code samples:

> You can also include fixed values for which no data exists to create additional columns.

Yes, I would like to create a pivot table with a fixed **ordered** set of column headings from a pre-existing list. Here's a simplified SQL query:

```
    TRANSFORM SUM(tblData.Losses) As TotalLosses
    SELECT tblData.LossType
    FROM tblData
    GROUP BY tblData.Region
    PIVOT tblData.Year;
```

I would like to add region names that are not in the table and I would like the regions to appear in a specific order. Yes, I can create a region listing table and left-join it: but that won't impose an arbitrary order, either - Crosstab queries always sort the columns left-to-right alphabetically.

And I might just want to add arbitrary fixed values for which no data exists.

Here's MSDN's information:

> Syntax

TRANSFORM *aggfunction*
    *selectstatement*
    PIVOT *pivotfield* [IN (*value1*[, *value2*[, …]])]

The TRANSFORM statement has these parts:

- *aggfunction*:	 An SQL aggregate function that operates on the selected data.
- *selectstatement*:	 A SELECT statement.
- *pivotfield*:	 The field or expression you want to use to create column headings in the query's result set.
- *value1*,*value2*:	 Fixed values used to create column headings.

...And the rest is just fluff for creating a plain-vanilla pivot table from textbook data.

So, my question is:

### Has anyone ever actually used fixed values to create column headings?

A sample of your SQL would be useful.

---

This is a question about the published syntax for Microsoft Access SQL.

Thank you for not asking why I want to do this, giving lengthy SQL examples that answer the question '*Is there ANSI SQL that does what a TRANSFORM statement does, by hardcoding everything*?' or pointing out that this would be easier in Postgres on a mainframe.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I was able to do this in Access with a fixed set of four values.

```
TRANSFORM Sum([Shape_Length]/5280) AS MILES
SELECT "ONSHORE" AS Type, Sum(qry_CurYrTrans.Miles) AS [Total Of Miles]
FROM qry_CurYrTrans
GROUP BY "ONSHORE"
PIVOT qry_CurYrTrans.QComb IN ('1_HCA_PT','2_HCA_PT','3_HCA_PT','4_HCA_PT');
```

My results were:

```
| Type     | Total Of Miles  | 1_HCA_PT  | 2_HCA_PT  | 3_HCA_PT  | 4_HCA_PT |
| ONSHORE  | 31.38           |           | 0.30      | 7.80      |          |
```

From this result, I can determine a few things:

- The values '2_HCA_PT' and '3_HCA_PT' do exist in column QComb from my source.
- The values '1_HCA_PT' and '4_HCA_PT' do *not* exist in column QComb from my source.
- There are additional values in column QComb from my source that aren't represented in the PIVOT column headings. I can tell because 31.38 > (0.30 + 7.80).

Comment: What I'd like to know is, how I can replace the null values with "0"?

Comment: If this is a question, you should consider it asking as a new question?

Comment: Good idea. I just did. ([Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234539/how-do-replace-nulls-in-a-crosstab-query-with-zeroes).)

Comment: EJ Mark - Nice, seems you got the answer as well. :)

Comment: Looks like PIVOT ...IN is doing more than I would expect: it's certainly doing more than the usual IN operator in a WHERE clause. That's useful, and I need to experiment with it (pity it's undocumented). Is this actually imposing an arbitrary order on the columns, though? Looks like they're still sorted alphanumerically...

Comment: I believe that the order is determined by the order that they are written in the IN clause. So, if the example above was rewritten as `IN ('4_HCA_PT','3_HCA_PT','2_HCA_PT','1_HCA_PT')`, I think you would see the column order change. Note that you should also be able to _exclude_ a column by excluding it from the IN clause. So, if you wanted to return only two columns (and exclude all others), you could write `IN ('4_HCA_PT','3_HCA_PT)`. I'm not sure if this is standard SQL, but I believe it works this way in MS Access.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(tblData.Losses) AS TotalLosses
SELECT tblData.Region, tblData.LossType
FROM tblData
GROUP BY tblData.Region, tblData.LossType
PIVOT tblData.Year In ('2001','2000');
```

The key being the list of years in the PIVOT statement. You might have to replace the ' with # for datetime datatypes.

Comment: Close, but no cigar: you're specifying a subset of the values available in tblData.Year - not supplying a list of arbitrary fixed items. These aren't  'fixed values for which no data exists' and they won't create extra columns if they're not already in tblData.

Comment: Also... You just scraped that SQL sample off the MSDN page, didn't you?

Comment: Nope. I have a similar situation, but I can't share code. The edited query above works on my end assuming text fields for the year. If you post the table schemea it would be eaiser to fix the query.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you're able to get it to return results, the "IN (value1, value2)" bit is just you specifying which pivoted columns you wish to return in your result set.

So for example, if without "IN (value1, value2)" your table looks like this:

| id | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | c | d |

Adding "IN ('2', '4')" Would return:

| id | 2 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | b | d |