# How do you replace nulls in a crosstab query with zeroes?

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot, crosstab

Based on the following SQL in Access...

```
TRANSFORM Sum([Shape_Length]/5280) AS MILES
SELECT "ONSHORE" AS Type, Sum(qry_CurYrTrans.Miles) AS [Total Of Miles]
FROM qry_CurYrTrans
GROUP BY "ONSHORE"
PIVOT qry_CurYrTrans.QComb IN ('1_HCA_PT','2_HCA_PT','3_HCA_PT','4_HCA_PT');
```

... my results returned the following datasheet:

```
| Type     | Total Of Miles  | 1_HCA_PT  | 2_HCA_PT  | 3_HCA_PT  | 4_HCA_PT |
| ONSHORE  | 31.38           |           | 0.30      | 7.80      |          |
```

This result is exactly what I want *except* I want to see zeroes in the cells that are null.

What are some options for doing this? If possible, I'd like to avoid using a subquery. I'd also prefer the query to remain editable in Access' Design View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use the Nz function, which will allow you to convert NULLs to another value.  In this case, I used the (optional) part of the function to say, "If Sum([Shape_Length]/5280) is NULL, set it to 0".  You **may** have to use quotes around the 0, I can't recall.

```
TRANSFORM Nz(Sum([Shape_Length]/5280), 0) AS MILES
SELECT "ONSHORE" AS Type, Sum(qry_CurYrTrans.Miles) AS [Total Of Miles]
FROM qry_CurYrTrans
GROUP BY "ONSHORE"
PIVOT qry_CurYrTrans.QComb IN ('1_HCA_PT','2_HCA_PT','3_HCA_PT','4_HCA_PT');
```