# Can I add dummy rows to a crosstab query in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot, crosstab

Is it possible to add dummy row headings to a crosstab query when the data doesn't exist in the source table/query? I'd like to indicate that I'm aware that a category exists, even though nothing currently falls under that category.

To illustrate, I'd like to take this output...

```
| Category    | Total  | Class 1 | Class 2   | Class 3  | Class 4  |
| PARTK2130   |  0.10  | 0.00    |  0.00     |  0.10    | 0.00     |
| PARTK3140   |  0.29  | 0.01    |  0.24     |  0.04    | 0.00     |
| PARTK4150   | 30.98  | 0.33    | 12.22     | 18.44    | 0.00     |
```

And make it look like this (notice the * New * rows)...

```
| Category    | Total | Class 1  | Class 2   | Class 3  | Class 4  |
| PARTK1120   |  0.00 |  0.00    |  0.00     |  0.00    | 0.00     | *New*
| PARTK2130   |  0.10 |  0.00    |  0.00     |  0.10    | 0.00     |
| PARTK3140   |  0.29 |  0.01    |  0.24     |  0.04    | 0.00     |
| PARTK4150   | 30.98 |  0.33    | 12.22     | 18.44    | 0.00     |
| PARTK5160   |  0.00 |  0.00    |  0.00     |  0.00    | 0.00     | *New*
| PARTK6170   |  0.00 |  0.00    |  0.00     |  0.00    | 0.00     | *New*
| PARTK7180   |  0.00 |  0.00    |  0.00     |  0.00    | 0.00     | *New*
```

The only way that I can think of doing this is by creating a new dummy source-table/query, populate it with some dummy records, then modifying my crosstab query as a UNION query that looks at this dummy source along with the original. I got it to work, but this seems like a like a lot of monkey business.

Indeed, I learned how to add extra columns when there is no data (see the Class 4 column and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234539/how-do-you-replace-nulls-in-a-crosstab-query-with-zeroes)), so I would think there's a trick to add extra rows too. Hoping anyway.

Here's the SQL:

```
TRANSFORM Format(Nz(Sum(qryPartK.MILES_OF_PHYS_LENGTH),0),"Fixed") 
AS SumOfMILES_OF_PHYS_LENGTH
SELECT IIf([PCT_SMYS]<=30,"PARTK2130",
IIf([PCT_SMYS]<=40,"PARTK3140", IIf([PCT_SMYS]<=50,"PARTK4150",
IIf([PCT_SMYS]<=60,"PARTK5160",IIf([PCT_SMYS]<=72,"PARTK6170",
IIf([PCT_SMYS]>72 And [PCT_SMYS]>=80,"PARTK7180",
IIf([PCT_SMYS]>80,"PARTK80MORE"))))))) AS Category, 
Sum(qryPartK.MILES_OF_PHYS_LENGTH) AS Total
FROM qryPartK
GROUP BY IIf([PCT_SMYS]<=30,"PARTK2130",
IIf([PCT_SMYS]<=40,"PARTK3140",IIf([PCT_SMYS]<=50,"PARTK4150",
IIf([PCT_SMYS]<=60,"PARTK5160",IIf([PCT_SMYS]<=72,"PARTK6170",
IIf([PCT_SMYS]>72 And [PCT_SMYS]>=80,"PARTK7180",
IIf([PCT_SMYS]>80,"PARTK80MORE")))))))
PIVOT qryPartK.CLASS_LOC_text In ("Class 1","Class 2","Class 3","Class 4");
```

Comment: Do you have a Category table with the distinct categories you want to display?  If so, look into using an `outer join`.

Comment: No, I do not. If I did, could you explain how I would go about using it to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use an `outer join` with a subquery:

```
select c.category, r.total, r.class1, r.class2, r.class3, r.class4
from (select 'PARTK1120' category 
      union all select 'PARTK2130'
      union all select 'PARTK3140'
      union all select 'PARTK4150'
      union all select 'PARTK5160'
      union all select 'PARTK6170'
      union all select 'PARTK7180') c 
left join yourresults r on c.category = r.category
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5f44/2)

You could use `coalesce` to turn the `null` values into `0`: `coalesce(r.total, 0) total`

Comment: I'm intrigued by this, but your code doesn't seem to be compatible with the Access SQL dialect. If there's a way to adapt it, I'd be interested in learning how.

Answer (score 0):

UNION made your data distinct. If category are distinct that it will show in result. If you will return only rows with value you must add `Where Total <> 0`.

EDIT

```
TRANSFORM Format(Nz(Sum(qryPartK.MILES_OF_PHYS_LENGTH),0),"Fixed") 
AS SumOfMILES_OF_PHYS_LENGTH
SELECT IIf([PCT_SMYS]<=30,"PARTK2130",
IIf([PCT_SMYS]<=40,"PARTK3140", IIf([PCT_SMYS]<=50,"PARTK4150",
IIf([PCT_SMYS]<=60,"PARTK5160",IIf([PCT_SMYS]<=72,"PARTK6170",
IIf([PCT_SMYS]>72 And [PCT_SMYS]>=80,"PARTK7180",
IIf([PCT_SMYS]>80,"PARTK80MORE"))))))) AS Category, 
Sum(qryPartK.MILES_OF_PHYS_LENGTH) AS Total
FROM qryPartK

WHERE Sum(qryPartK.MILES_OF_PHYS_LENGTH)<>0

GROUP BY IIf([PCT_SMYS]<=30,"PARTK2130",
IIf([PCT_SMYS]<=40,"PARTK3140",IIf([PCT_SMYS]<=50,"PARTK4150",
IIf([PCT_SMYS]<=60,"PARTK5160",IIf([PCT_SMYS]<=72,"PARTK6170",
IIf([PCT_SMYS]>72 And [PCT_SMYS]>=80,"PARTK7180",
IIf([PCT_SMYS]>80,"PARTK80MORE")))))))
PIVOT qryPartK.CLASS_LOC_text In ("Class 1","Class 2","Class 3","Class 4");
```

Try to add WHERE.

Comment: Or if total it is not sum of all classes, you should add `Where Total <>0 and [Class 1] <> 0` etc.

Comment: I'm not completely following, but I'm also not currently using a UNION query. In fact, I'm hoping to avoid it.

Comment: Please write you query, it would be helpful.

Comment: Nope. Error message: "Cannot have aggregate function WHERE clause (Sum(qryPartK.MILES_OF_PHYS_LENGTH)<>0)."