# How to order the category axis of a report chart by value in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a database of lake vegetation species over time. The goal is to get this set up so a user could go in and select a lake and a sample date and the report would automatically generate summary charts based on a table which is created in the background and replaced each time the query runs.

The query currently works in the background generated by a button by pulling out the selected data based on the form input into a query, which summarizes the species by frequency and density. Then a Make Table query runs to convert that data to a table, linked to a pivot chart. (I am using MS Access 2010)

The SQL behind the chart is as follows:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(TempTable_FrequencyofSpecies.[Frequency]) AS SumOfFrequency 
SELECT TempTable_FrequencyofSpecies.[SpeciesCommonName] 
FROM TempTable_FrequencyofSpecies 
GROUP BY TempTable_FrequencyofSpecies.[SpeciesCommonName] 
ORDER BY Sum(TempTable_FrequencyofSpecies.[Frequency]) DESC 
PIVOT TempTable_FrequencyofSpecies.[DensityDesc];
```

The table (called 'TempTable_FrequencyofSpecies) `Order By` property is also set to:

```
   [Frequency] DESC
```

What I'm wondering is if there is something I'm missing in the SQL or another way to order the category x-axis by the summarized value (in this case, `Sum of Frequency`) and have that save to the chart template each time the data is replaced.

The `Order By` property and `ORDER BY` clause in the SQL statement for the chart has no effect.

Comment: If there is any query that you already tried - please attach it.

Comment: @SavannahW ... please edit your post with SQL query with formatting. See link below tags. Then delete these long comments. Also, please describe what type of charts these are? Pivot charts (discontinued from MS Access 2013+)? Or OLE Charts? Again, do so in post not in comments.

Comment: How many values are you pivoting? To set order of columns, specify column headings in the CROSSTAB Column Headings property. The PIVOT clause would look something like: `PIVOT TempTable_FrequencyofSpecies.[DensityDesc] IN ("A", "B", "C");` . Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html#ColHead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crosstab Queries: using fixed values to create additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498570/crosstab-queries-using-fixed-values-to-create-additional-columns)

Comment: @June7 - I'm not sure I understand what you mean by your comment..There would be a lot of species per lake to specify, and the order would change based on the lake and the total sum of the count of species...so specifying a specific set of columns wouldn't work.

Comment: Edit question to provide sample data and desired output.